# What happens to a contract when company is disolved?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, real-estate

I have been renting a property (residential) for 10 months from a limited company.

I wanted to move out of the property recently, they informed me I still  have two months left on my contract, i would need to pay for. Then i would also need to pay £400 in checking out fees, Im not sure what the "checking out fees" are for, but i had to pay a similar "checking in fee" when i picked up the keys, granted this was a bit less.

Shocked i looked through my contract and realized i had in fact agreed to this.

However, The name on the contract for the company i have been paying, has been dissolved according to companies house

> Final Gazette dissolved via voluntary strike-off

The company filled for this a week before i even signed the contract with them.

Is there anything I can do here? I have never been informed of anything that has changed regarding the company.

**Edit
Update. There is nothing in my contract stating that it can be switched to a different entity.

The landlord name on the contract is the company that is now dissolved. The director is still the person I am dealing with. I signed a contract agreeing said company will be my landlord but that company doesn't exist...is this contract void?

Thanks!

Comment: If the company has been dissolved its like dealing with a dead person.  If there are "heirs to the estate" (ie creditors or people who have taken over) then they can quite possibly force you to honor the contract.  I expect this will depend on the exact terms of your contract.    You may want to clarify if this is a residential lease, and what this £400 is for - you may find that regardless of what the contract says thay can't charge you (I'm not an expert on UK law, but its not legal in NZ regardless of what the contract says)

Comment: Also, were you notified of their successor?

Comment: I have never been informed of any change to the company, never been informed to pay too a different account, my dealings with the company have been with one person, who is listed as the director of the now dissolved company. Seems really dodgy to me. The fees i have no clue what they are for, i have heard of a check out fee before but this is usually around a fraction of what I'm expected to pay.

Comment: The question to ask then is "who has standing to sue you if you don't pay them". THIS IS NOT LEGAL ADVICE, but I might be inclined to dtop paying them, and then negotiate the fee away if they come knocking - remrmbering to point out they have no standing.

Comment: So the account you have been paying into belongs to a non-existent company? Sounds like something the bank should be told about.

Comment: Yeah the account has never changed, the company i have been paying is dissolved, it has been since i've been paying them....I don't know how to report this sort of thing? Do i got to lawyer or to the police?

Comment: I dont know if the account belonged to the company, or if its just the directors bank account....

Comment: Does the company own the property, or (more likely) is it a letting agency acting on behalf of a landlord? Either way, get in touch with the company to clarify the matters you've raised. If the latter, and if you're still concerned, it couldn't hurt to get in touch with the landlord (details should appear in the tenancy agreement; or failing that, you can get them for a small fee from the Land Registry website).

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff the company own the property, they arent acting on behalf of the landlord they are the landlord...and the letting agency...

Comment: Read your contract again - look for the paragraph which says something about the company having the right to "assign" it to another entity (or similar wording).

Comment: @alpha "the company own the property": no, the company does not own the property, because the company does not exist.  Someone else owns the property.

Comment: Wacky thought - it *might* pay to take legal advice and ask about squatting law. It is just conceivable to me that you may want to stay there (rent free) and if you pull it off you could land up owning it. (**Its an extreme long shot*" - but take a read of https://www.gov.uk/squatting-law/squatters-rights-to-property to show I'm not totally mad)

Comment: @phoog true but on the contract, the company is named as the landlord, the director owns the property, but the company has been dissolved. I'm just trying to work out if the contract is void.

Comment: @alpha it might be better to think of it this way, assuming that the company *did* own the property when it was dissolved: when the company was dissolved, ownership of the property passed to someone else.  Who is that?  If the company was dissolved after you signed the lease, did the company's rights and responsibilities under the lease pass to the new owner of the property (that's how it usually works when a rental property is transferred in the US, at least)?  If the company was dissolved before you signed the lease, is your lease somehow a valid contract with some other party?

Comment: "the company is named as the landlord, the director owns the property": these are contradictory. The owner of the property (whether a person or company) is the landlord by definition (for a flat, it would be the leaseholder rather than owner, but the principle is the same). A company may act as a letting agent, but they are not the landlord. A landlord is free to change or remove a letting agent.

Comment: (continued) In particular, if the landlord of a property has changed, the new landlord is required to notify the tenant. All obligations of the tenant and the new landlord remain as they were.

Comment: On the contract. It says "LANDLORD: Comapny Name"....That company is dissolved. The director of that dissolved company owns the property, i found that out from doing a land registry check, but his name is not on the contract. Only the company that he used to have. So on my contract it states my landlord is the company that has been dissolved. Ownership of the property has never changed, but the company has gone. The director still owns the property.

Comment: @alpha: a month on, can you provide an update?

Comment: alpha, your previous comment says that the contract names the company as the landlord, but that "ownership of the property never changed." Are you sure of that? If the director was the registered owner of the property when you signed the contract, but the contract said that the company was the owner, then it seems that there were serious problems with the contract (especially if the company was actually dissolved *before* you signed the contract). @SteveMelnikoff if the contract listed the wrong party as owner, would the contract be invalid?

Answer (score 2):

*Having received clarification in the comments, and bearing in mind that I'm not a lawyer or expert:*

One of following is probably true:

1. The landlord (and owner) always was, and still is, the director, and the company was never the landlord; hence the contract contains an error.
2. The landlord (and owner) was the company, but at some point, the property was transferred out of the company to the director, and the company was dissolved.

If it's (2), this is legal, as property can always be sold or otherwise transferred (e.g. by inheritance). If the property has a tenant, then **the new owner is bound by the tenancy agreement, and so is the tenant.** So in that respect, nothing has changed.

However, the new owner is [required to inform the tenant](https://www.landlordlawblog.co.uk/2017/01/23/warning-new-landlords-taking-existing-tenancies/) of a change of ownership within 2 months, or face prosecution and a fine. (There may also be tax implications for the company and the director.)

The important thing here is when (or if) a change of ownership happened, relative to the start of the tenancy and the dissolution of the company.

**UPDATE:** as revealed in a comment, it's (1): the company was dissolved before the tenancy was started. As it's impossible for a company which doesn't exist to be a party to a contract, this would suggest that this tenancy agreement is not valid.

**However,** a tenancy between the actual owner of the property, and the tenant, does still exist. This is because a tenancy is deemed to exist if all the normal conditions (e.g. paying rent to the owner in exchange for use of the property) are met, [even if it's never written down](https://www.landlordlawblog.co.uk/2015/06/08/what-happens-if-you-dont-have-a-written-tenancy-agreement/).

But a consequence of this is that any check-out fee cannot be insisted on, since that was part of the invalid contract.

So, to return to the original question, if the owner insists on you paying the check-out fee, it might be possible to challenge it on these grounds - but I would not recommend going down that path without speaking to someone who is an expert in these matters.

Comment: The company was dissolved before I signed the tenancy it dissolved September, I signed and moved in October. The ownership has never changed according to the land registry.

Comment: A dissolved company still exists as an entity for purposes of winding up its affairs. Dissolving a company is not equivalent to the situation before a company is formed when it doesn't exist. It can enter into contracts, sue, etc.

Comment: @ohwilleke: sure, but even if it did exist, a company can't act as landlord if it doesn't own the property. And, as far as I can tell, at the point where a British company is dissolved, its assets immediately pass to the Crown. Hence it can't be the landlord. Is this not the case here?

Comment: "as far as I can tell, at the point where a British company is dissolved, its assets immediately pass to the Crown." I don't think that this is accurate. And, generally, a non-property owner can manage property as a general agent for the property owner and call themselves a landlord with the owner's permission.

Comment: @ohwilleke: (a) "[When a company is dissolved, all of its assets pass to the Crown](https://www.gov.uk/claiming-money-or-property-from-dissolved-company). (b) Not in the UK. There is a clear distinction between a landlord and their agent, and details of **both** must be appear in the tenancy agreement.

Comment: Yeah i think i will pay for some legal advice on this one....I dont think i need to pay the fees, i dont mind paying the rent, but if i have signed a contract with a company, and that company doesnt exist i feel like that contract should be void. Why am i paying fees to a non existent company?...

Comment: @alpha: another thought: if you refuse to pay any end-of-tenancy fees, the landlord may apply to take it out of your deposit. You can then raise this with the [Tenancy Deposit Scheme](https://www.tenancydepositscheme.com/deposit-disputes.html), and let them decide.